# Android Push Notifications: getting SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE as response

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I wrote code for push notifications.But response is "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE". I tried so many times. I want to know the registration id of the device. Please any one help me how to get the registration id of the device. I install the google cloud messaging library in sdk manager too,.

My code:
GCMIntentService :

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService{

    private static int count = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(null);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        handleMessage(this, intent);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void handleMessage(Context mContext, Intent intent) {

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int icon = R.drawable.reload_logo;
        try {
            Bundle gcmData = intent.getExtras();
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = null;

            Intent gotoIntent = new Intent();
            gotoIntent.setClassName(mContext,"com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.SplashActivity");//Start activity when user taps on notification.
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                    (int) (Math.random() * 100), gotoIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon,gcmData.getString("message"), when);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext,
                    "Reload.in",//title
                    intent.getExtras().getString("message"), contentIntent);//message
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            count++;
            notificationManager.notify(count, notification);//This will generate seperate notification each time server sends.
        }catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver :

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

GcmUtilities :

```
public class GcmUtilities {

    public static String GCMProjectId="xxxxxxxx"; 

    /**
     * This method used to get GCM project id.
     * 
     * @return represented {@link String}
     */
    public static String getGCMProjectId() {
        return GCMProjectId;
    }
}
```

MainActivty:

```
 public void enableGCM() {

        try {
            if (checkPlayServices()) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
                String regid = getRegistrationId();

                if (regid==null|regid.isEmpty()) {
                    registerInBackground();
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("GCM", "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        try {
            int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {

                } else {
                    Log.i("GCM", "This device is not supported.");
                    finish();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(SplashActivity.this);
                    }
                    String regid = gcm.register(GcmUtilities.getGCMProjectId());
                    storeRegistrationId(regid);
                    Log.v("TAG_GSMMMMM_regid", "" + regid);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.v("TAG_GSMMMMM",""+ ex.getMessage().toString());

                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(String regId) {
        Editor editor = m_sharedPreference.edit();
        editor.putString("regid", regId);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getRegistrationId(){
        String registration_id=m_sharedPreference.getString("regid","");
        return registration_id;
    }
```

Manifest:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <receiver android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="com.reloadapp.reload" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.GCMIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: please any one help me out

Answer (score 0):

There may be lot of reasons for this error. Here are the possible solutions:

- The server couldn't process the request in time. Retry the same request &  Honor the Retry-After header if it is included in the response from the GCM Connection Server.
- Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry, wait at least two second before the next one, then 4 seconds and so on). If you're sending multiple messages, delay each one independently by an additional random amount to avoid issuing a new request for all messages at the same time.
- GCM only permits a threshhold limit to send a single message to 1000 devices through multicast devices. If you are sending large number of messages in a single shot though your app server chances are good that they might get discarded.
- The payload data limit sent through GCM server is of 4kb. If the data exceeds that limit than GCM just discards these messages.
- Make sure the package name is preceded over each permission you specify. In your manifest file is the package name `com.google.android` or  `com.reloadapp.reload`. It should be similar to this

  ```
  <permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  ```

Hope that Helps!!

Comment: without sending the registration id of mobile to server i am getting push message. why it happend?